# MPI_ANY_SOURCE in non blocking receive (MPI_Irecv)

Tags: mpi

I use LD_PRELOAD to override the MPI_Irecv function with my own function to do some debugging of the MPI_Irecv function.

Here, my wrapper function "myMPI_Irecv.c" code:

```
int MPI_Irecv(void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int source,
                    int tag, MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Request * request)
    {
         int rang_Irecv;
         MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rang_Irecv);

         printf(" Calling MPI_Irecv, je suis processeur=%d, source=%d, buffer=%p\n", rang_Irecv,source,buf);
    
         return PMPI_Irecv(buf, count, datatype, source, tag, comm, request);
    }
```

After running my MPI application (I am using MPICH):
I found that there are some calls of MPI_ANY_SOURCE, because I found SOURCE=-2 when I print the source.

My question, is how to know which source (sender) for the nonblocking receive MPI_Irecv ?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

I suspect (you didn't include enough code) that you are reading the source of the receive call. Instead you have to look at the `MPI_Wait` call for that receive. It outputs a status object, and you can investigate `mystatus.MPI_SOURCE` to see where the message actually came from.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In my project, the MPI_Irecv calls are included into an extern library, so that I cannot modify the code, But, is there something I can do inside the  wrapper function? I tried to change "return PMPI_Irecv" with return "PMI_recv" to print mystatus.MPI_SOURCE but it doesn't work!

Comment: Where is the `Wait` call? You can not have `Irecv` without a `Wait` call. That's where you get the status object.